# How to count the number of digits in double/float C++

Tags: c++, math, fractions

I'm trying to count the number of digits in fractional part of double, but something is going wrong and I getting infinite loop:

```
double pi = 3.141592;
int counter = 0;
for (; pi != int(pi); ++counter)
    pi *= 10;
cout << counter << endl;
```

I'v just read about this problem, however I can't find a good solution. Is there really no better way than convert a number to string and count chars? I suppose there's more correct method.

Comment: print out `pi` value in every step and see for yourself

Comment: There is almost no such thing as 'number of digits' in floating-point number. There is such a thing as 'precision'.

Comment: http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=051046049052049053057050 -- in particular note: "Most accurate representation = 3.14159200000000016217427400989E0"

Comment: @drorco it's a link to this post)

Comment: Well,the code works fine on my machine

Comment: related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083304/c-c-counting-the-number-of-decimals

Comment: @RajeevSingh, it's my mistake, I have another number in my code and pi just as example. Try with 3.1415, it won't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Floating point numbers in computer use binary (base 2, zeros and ones, like almost all numbers in computers). So there is an exact number of binary digits in them, more in `double` and less in `float`. However, if you convert a decimal constant like 3.141592 to `double`, then print it with full accuracy, you don't get same number back. This is because converting the decimals between bases isn't exact in general (it's similar effect effect you get with 1/3 having infinite decimal expansion 0.33...). Example:

```
double pi = 3.141592;
std::cout << std::setprecision(100) << pi << std::endl;
```

Outputs for me:

```
3.14159200000000016217427400988526642322540283203125
```

---

So when you start multiplying this by 10 in your question code, you can see how it doesn't become an exact integer in a long time (and by then it is far beyond range of `int`), so your condition is never true (either there is fractional part, or the double is too large to fit in integer).

In other words, what you ask, counting digits directly from a `double`, makes no sense. You first need to print it as string, otherwise you don't really *have* a number of decimal digits to count. Of course you could micro-optimize this and skip the actual conversion to ASCII or UTF-16 string, but I don't see a scenario where that would be worth the trouble (except perhaps as a learning excercise).

If you need exact decimal digits in calculations, you need a special number type, which doesn't store fractions in binary. Example of such numeric type is [Java BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Comment: Are you sure that you can actually get infinite expansions with base-2 floating point values? I'm pretty sure that you can't, and would likely be able to derive a proof for that (or simply find one on the internet)... (The reasoning would be along the lines of "Base-2 decimals are sums of `2^-n` which for each `n` has a finite base-10 reprentation, so the sum must have a finite number of digits, too.")

Answer (score 3):

Atharva MR Fire here.

I've made a simple function that can count number of digits in a double.(float has 8 bits so just change 16 to 8 and make some other necessary changes.)

```
int get_float_digits(double num)
{
    int digits=0;
    double ori=num;//storing original number
    long num2=num;
    while(num2>0)//count no of digits before floating point
    {
        digits++;
        num2=num2/10;
    }
    if(ori==0)
        digits=1;
    num=ori;
    double no_float;
    no_float=ori*(pow(10, (16-digits)));
    long long int total=(long long int)no_float;
    int no_of_digits, extrazeroes=0;
    for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
    {
        int dig;
        dig=total%10;
        total=total/10;
        if(dig!=0)
            break;
        else
            extrazeroes++;
    }
    no_of_digits=16-extrazeroes;
    return no_of_digits;
}
```

If you want to get just the number of decimals, add a code `no_of_digits=no_of_digits-digits;` at the end, before the return function.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
num = pi - int(pi);
while abs(num) >= 0.0000001{
    num = num * 10;
    count = count + 1;
    num = num - int(num);
}
cout<< count<< endl;
```

for more information, you can read this [C/C++ counting the number of decimals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083304/c-c-counting-the-number-of-decimals).

Answer (score 2):

1. **Of coarse it is infinite loop**

   When you are multiplying floating point variable with fractional part some numbers tend to behave as irrational on **FPU** arithmetics (due to rounding errors). So no matter how much you multiply by `10` there is still some fractional part ...
2. **how to do it instead**

   You need to look at mantissa in binary instead and see where the least significant set bit is. so:

   ```
   union
       {
       double lf;
       BYTE db[8];
       } pi;

   pi.lf = 3.141592;
   // here just output the BYTES to memo,screen or whatever
   mm_log->Lines->Add(AnsiString().sprintf("%x",pi.db[0])); // LSB
   mm_log->Lines->Add(AnsiString().sprintf("%x",pi.db[1]));
   mm_log->Lines->Add(AnsiString().sprintf("%x",pi.db[2]));
   mm_log->Lines->Add(AnsiString().sprintf("%x",pi.db[3]));
   mm_log->Lines->Add(AnsiString().sprintf("%x",pi.db[4]));
   mm_log->Lines->Add(AnsiString().sprintf("%x",pi.db[5]));
   mm_log->Lines->Add(AnsiString().sprintf("%x",pi.db[6]));
   mm_log->Lines->Add(AnsiString().sprintf("%x",pi.db[7])); // MSB
   ```

   The result is that pi is stored as:

   ```
   0x400921FAFC8B007A hex
   0100 0000 0000 1001 0010 0001 1111 1010 1111 1100 1000 1011 0000 0000 0111 1010 bin
   ```

   According to [Wiki IEEE_754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) the double is divided like this:

   ```
   sign     = 0 bin -> +
   exponent = 100 0000 0000 bin - 1023 dec = 1
   mantissa = 1.1001 0010 0001 1111 1010 1111 1100 1000 1011 0000 0000 0111 1010 bin
   ```

   Note that mantissa has added `1.` which is not present in the number representation !!!. Also the exponent is biased that is why the `-1023` is there. Now when applied bit shift left by exponent we got

   ```
   pi = 11.001 0010 0001 1111 1010 1111 1100 1000 1011 0000 0000 0111 1010 bin
   ```

   Now we look for least set significant bit position

   ```
   pi = 11.001 0010 0001 1111 1010 1111 1100 1000 1011 0000 0000 0111 1010 bin
                                                                        ^
   ```

   It is at weight `2^-50=1/2^50=8.8817841970012523233890533447266e-16=~10e-16` (50th position after decimal point) meaning you got around ~16 decimal numbers of the rounded `pi=3.141592` representation. When you print it properly you will see:

   ```
   3.14159200000000016
   ```

   You can also use `n10=~log10(n2)` to estimate the number of decadic decimals `n10` safely represented by `n2` binary decimals. But for low `n2` is a bit irregular. for more info see

   - [How do you print the EXACT value of a floating point number?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18401040/2521214)

   From which for `n2=50` is `n10=15` which is pretty close to that `~16` decimals. Meaning that the `3.14159200000000016` should be truncated to `3.141592000000000` if just safe decadic digits may be present.